# Allow users to add items to a list but do not allow them to view/edit it

Tags: list-view

I have already created a form for users to submit questions to a Q&A list. After the questions is submitted, I would like the admin to be able to view the question, provide an answer and published it (by selecting a yes/no option) only (But I don't want the users to be able to see it on this page). And then I would like to display the published items on another page (a web part page). I am not sure if and how I can let them create an items, but not modify/view it on one page while display the published items to them on another pages as I am new to SharePoint. May somebody advice how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question SharePoint SE:

- [Anonymous access: Add an Item to List without allowing to View the List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69426/anonymous-access-add-an-item-to-list-without-allowing-to-view-the-list)

In standard permissions, `Add` is higher than `Read` so your solution cannot rely on the built-in forms (new, display, edit), unless you are willing to manipulate permissions for every list item.

You can though build your own form for adding list items. By restricting the access to the list you make it impossible to read existing items.

But users could still add list items through your custom form.

The actual adding of list items is achieved through elevation. Here you have two choices:

- A Full Trust Elevation [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)
- Elevation through App: [App Only Permissions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/02/23/sharepoint-2013-app-only-policy-made-easy.aspx). Basically your app has more rights for this particular list than a user. This solution works on Premises and Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can use unique permission for an item. In this scenario you can use a SharePoint list with your custom content type. All that you need is to set an event handler to add and update actions.

pros: you should not create custom forms.

cons: you have limitations for items with unique permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Well:
If you're using separate pages for entering a question and showing questions and answers (instead of showing the list directly somehow), that's what I understood wou want to do:
- just show a textarea with an insert databind in a DataView webpart on the "post your question here" page, and that's it. So there is no reason for SharePoint / the browser, to show anything else on this page and you can handle the user rights on a page-group basis as usual.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox columns="60" runat="server" id="question{$Pos}" text="" TextMode="MultiLine" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('question',$Pos),'Text','TextChanged','','ID', 12.ddwrt:EscapeDelims(@ID), 13.'@question')}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow to view only items that were created by the user.

To set up this settings go to the `List Settings -> Advanced Settings`, set R`ead items that were created by the user` in the Item-level Permissions section.

[Can you restrict a list to add item only but not read?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22713/can-you-restrict-a-list-to-add-item-only-but-not-read)