# Upload file page on sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, browsers

I would like to create a blank page with an upload button.

I want visitors to be able to upload a file to my documentlibrary. But i dont want visitors to have access to the files when they are uploaded.

How would i go about to create a blank page that have a "browse file" button and then a upload button. So the user can upload a file and then the file is stored in a folder that i decide.

Answer (score 0):

you have build a custom solution for this. You can create an add-on with either app only permissions or with service accounts so the app will provide admin rights to upload the files and nothing else.

you can refer the complete details below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/app-only-elevated-privileges-sharepoint-add-in

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page with JavaScript which uploads files to library:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx
You'll also need to create special permission level via code (CSOM/JSOM):
[Can you restrict a list to add item only but not read?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22713/can-you-restrict-a-list-to-add-item-only-but-not-read)

Comment: Here's good example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-file-to-document-library-in-sharepoint-2016-javascript-object-model/